# WSO2 Identity Server - Add Service Provider using XML

Tags: xml, wso2, configuration-files, service-provider, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 SP1

I am struggling to get Service Providers that I have registered via XML to work correctly.  I registered them all in the wso2is-5.0.0/repository/conf/security/sso-idp-config.xml and when Identity Server starts up, it notes that "A SSO Service Provider is register for : nameofSP" for each entry.

The problem I am running into is that the same entry, if it were instead registered in the UI, I can get a full login process to work with my service provider.  When the same information is in that XML instead, my service provider complains about not wanted to accept the POST coming from the IDP.

I had used this as a guide, but it leaves a few things ambiguious and tangled up with federation stuff: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Adding+a+Service+Provider+and+Identity+Provider+Using+Configuration+Files

No less, diffing the SSO trace of the successful and failure logins showed two different sets of query parameters for the redirects to the authenticationendpoint webapp....

Good one:

```
Referer: https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do?passiveAuth=false&forceAuth=false&type=samlsso&commonAuthCallerPath=%2Fsamlsso&relyingParty=sp_alias_jsimon&null=&sessionDataKey=94401b04-ba30-400d-9807-22363706e5d3&relyingParty=sp_alias_jsimon&type=samlsso&sp=sp_alias_jsimon&isSaaSApp=false&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator:LOCAL
```

Bad one:

```
Referer: https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do?passiveAuth=false&forceAuth=false&commonAuthCallerPath=%2Fsamlsso&relyingParty=sp_alias_jsimon&type=samlsso&null=&sessionDataKey=43a231b1-5c0b-4202-9164-ae924d5f477e&relyingParty=sp_alias_jsimon&type=samlsso&sp=default&isSaaSApp=true&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator:LOCAL
```

As you can see, in the good one the param sp equals my service provider 'sp_alias_jsimon' and isSaaSApp=false, whereas in the bad attempt sp=defaul and isSassSApp=true.  I'm assuming this is affecting how it fires off the authentication response back to the service provider.

I think information may been picked up from this config:
 wso2is-5.0.0/repository/conf/identity/service-providers/default.xml

So according to the documentation I should've been able to make a config in that same folder with the name of the service provider entity, in my case sp_alias_jsimon.xml and maybe it would pick up whatever it needs.  I tried that and it doesn't appear to be using the information.  Wrong naming scheme?  Maybe there's a special way to put SAML settings?

What am I misinterpreting?  What just isn't explained?  Is there another bug?